# $|f|$ has a global minimum where $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is any polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

The following Lemma is used in a proof for the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, but I cannot understand some steps.

> Lemma: Let  $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$  be any polynomial function.
> Then there exists a point  $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$  where the function
> $|f|$  attains its minimum value in  $\mathbb{R}$.

The proof starts like this:

> If  $f$  is a constant polynomial function, then the statement of the
> Lemma is trivially true since  $|f|$  attains its minimum value at
> every point in  $\mathbb{C}$ . So choose, e.g.,  $z_0=0$.
>
> If  $f$  is not constant, then the degree of the polynomial defining
> $f$  is at least one. In this case, we can denote  $f$  explicitly by
>
> $f(z)=a_n z^n + ... + a_1 z + a_0$
>
> with $a_n \neq 0$. Now, assume  $z \neq 0$ , and set
> $A=max\{|a_0|,…,|a_{n−1}|\}$ . We can obtain a lower bound for
> $|f(z)|$  as follows:
>
> $f(z)=|a_n| |z|^n |1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \frac{1}{z}+...+\frac{a_0}{a_n} \frac{1}{z^n}| \leq |a_n| |z|^n (1 - \frac{A}{|a_n|} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|z|^k})=|a_n| |z|^n (1 - \frac{A}{|a_n|} \frac{1}{|z|-1})$.

I don't see how these two steps follow. We can distribute the absolute value over all the factors, but how does one turn the second factor from $1+...$ into a $1-...$ using an infinite sum? After that it seems like an application of a geometric series, but how do we know that $|z|>1$?

I've been stuck for quite some while now with no notable progress. Am I missing anything obvious here?

Edit:

The next step of the proof is a follows (so it justifies the use of the formula for the geometric series):

> For all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| \geq 2$, we can further
> simplify this expression and obtain
>
> $ (*) |f(z)| \geq |a_n| |z|^n (1 - \frac{2A}{|a_n| |z|})$.

It follows from this inequality that there is an $R > 0$ such that $|f(z)| > |f(0)|$, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|z| > R$.

Now this confuses me once again. We have $|f(0)|=a_0$, so how does this follow from the inequality given above? I think it ought to have something to do with the definiton of $A$, but I can't quite figure it out.

Could anyone please provide a hint or an explanation?

Comment: The minus sign is like this; $|1+b| \ge 1 - |b|$.  Can you deduce this from the triangle inequality?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I've figured it out by now, but I'm stuck on the final statement (see the edit). Could you also help me on that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need geometric series, etc., in order to prove the Lemma. As you remark, we can assume
$$f(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0,\qquad n\geq1,\qquad a_n\ne0\ .$$
This implies$${f(z)\over z^n}=a_n+{a_{n-1}\over z}+\ldots+{a_0\over z^n}\to a_n\quad\bigl(|z|\to\infty\bigr)\ ,$$
so that there is an $R>0$ with
$$\left|{f(z)\over z^n}\right|>{|a_n|\over2}\qquad\bigl(|z|>R\bigr)\ .$$
From this we can infer that there is an $R'\geq R$ with
$$\bigl|f(z)\bigr|>|z|^n{|a_n|\over2}>|a_0|\qquad\bigl(|z|>R'\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
On the compact set $\overline{D_{R'}}$ the continuous function $z\mapsto\bigl|f(z)\bigr|$ assumes a global minimum $\>\leq|f(0)|=|a_0|$. Due to $(1)$ this minimum value is not assumed when $|z|>R'$, hence is the global minimum of $|f|$ on ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What exactly is it that guarantees the existence of $R'$ in (1). In particular, why does the last inequality in (1) hold true? Is it the Archimedian property? I have a feeling that it's the same argument as for $(*)$ in my post, so I'd appreciate if you could elaborate on this.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy: The quantities $|a_n|$ and $|a_0|$ are given. As $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}|z|^n=\infty$ we can be sure that $(1)$ is true when $|z|>R'$ for a suitable $R'$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am still trying to figure out how one can decuce the result you gave from the inequality in my post.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \frac{1}{z}+...+\frac{a_0}{a_n} \frac{1}{z^n}\right|\ge1-\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|\frac1{|z|}-\ldots-\left|\frac{a_0}{a_n}\right|\frac1{|z|^n}\ge$$

$$\ge1-\frac A{|a_n|}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{|z|^k}\ge1-\frac A{|a_n|}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{|z|^k}$$

where $\;A=\max\left\{\,|a_0|,\,|a_1|,\ldots,|a_{n-1}|\,\right\}\;$

About the $\;|z|>1\iff\frac1{|z|}<1\;$ : you're right, there's no data about this in the part you copied. Where did you get this proof from?

Comment: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Book%3A_Linear_Algebra_(Schilling_Nachtergaele_and_Lankham)/03%3A_3._The_fundamental_theorem_of_algebra_and_factoring_polynomials/3.01%3A_The_Fundamental_Theorem_of_Algebra

Comment: @DerivativesGuy  Fine. In the continuation he makes a remark about what happens in case of $\;|z|Z>2\;$, but in fact you can from the beginning assume $\;|z|>1\;$ , since for $\;|z|\le1\;$ it is clear $\;|f(z)|\;$ attains a minimum (and maximum) value by Weierstrass Theorem, as that is a continuous function on a compact set...

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that. Thanks for your help. I think I still don't get the first inequality in your answer. Are we using a property of the absolute value/norm?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Yes, that's a rather basic property of abosulte value: for any $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;|x+y|\ge |x|-|y|\;$ Try to prove it, it is very easy and part of regular high schools mathematics curriculum.

Comment: Ah, yes. It simply follows from the triangle inequality. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is constant, then any complex number is a global minimum.
If $\deg f\geq 1$ and $a_0=0$, then $0$ is a global minimum.
If $\deg f\geq 1$ and $a_0\neq 0$, we need two lemmas:

1. $|f|\to \infty$ if $|t|\to \infty$ (Indeed, write $|f(t)|=|a_nt^n||1+...|$ with $|t|>0$).
2. The continuous map $|f|:\mathbb C\to \mathbb R$, $t\mapsto |f(t)|$ attains its minimum (and maximum) if $t$ is in the closed disc of radius $R$ for any $R>0$ (see Baby Rudin 4.16).

From 1., there is some $R_0>0$ such that $|f(t)|> |a_0|>0$ outside the closed disc of radius $R_0$. From 2., this closed disc contains $z_0$ such that $|f(z_0)|\leq |f(t)|$ for any $t$ in this disc. In particular, for $t=0$, $|f(z_0)|\leq |f(0)|=|a_0|$ so that, $|f(z_0)|\leq |a_0|<|f(t)|$ for any $t$ outside this disc. This shows that $z_0$ is a global minimum.